# Mark all checkboxes in jquery datatable using external 'dom' checkbox

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a datatable with checkboxes in the first column. I have also kept a checkbox outside the table grid utilizing the dom attribute of the datatable. The idea is to use this checkbox as a 'Select all' checkbox. How to I iterate over the rows of the table to pick the individual checkboxes in the rows and change their styling to 'selected'

```
var callBackToMarkAll = function() {
  // Logic of the type: $(dtab).find('.selectcheckbox').attr('className')=>convert class to selected;
}
var dtab = $("#example").DataTable(function() {
  // code
  columnDefs: [{
    orderable: false,
    className: 'select-checkbox',
    targets: 0
  }],
  select: {
    style: 'multi',
    selector: 'td:first-child'
  },
  dom: '<"chk">ftipr'
    // more code
});
$("div.chk").html('<input id="cBox" type="checkbox"/>');
$("#cBox").click(callBackToMarkAll);
```

Comment: `$(dtab).find('.selectcheckbox').attr('checked', true);` -- or better, get the checked value of the originating checkbox click event, and set them all to that. Of course, I'm just riffing here -- that's how I'd do it, given a collection of dom nodes.

Comment: It is not working for me. I tried doing $(dab).find('tr').addClass('selected'); However $('tr').addClass('selected') does get all rows checked.  But that is not proper solution as I want the rows for the specific table

Comment: On a side note: Change `$(#example)` to `$("#example")`?